# Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable , how can i solve this?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I have uploaded two `csv`s and I'm using a `reactive()` in `shinyr` to manipulate the `csv` data. However am getting this error

> Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Am quite new to R, how can I get past that error?! Thanks

```
    ##datasets
    datatables
                 Client Amount     Reason
    1 0000001440MACT800 100000  6866755276

    datatable
                CLIENTID UPDATED.BY DEPOSIT.TYPE       AMOUNT       UPDATED.ON
    1  0000001451MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit   100,000.00  7/14/2016 09:33
    2  0000001002MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit   100,000.00  7/14/2016 09:23
    3  0000001006MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit 1,500,000.00  10/3/2016 11:48
    4  0000001440MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit   100,000.00  7/12/2016 14:13
    5  0000001022MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit   150,000.00  10/6/2016 14:23
    6  0000001024MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit   100,000.00  7/20/2016 08:18
    7  0000001032MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit   100,000.00  7/20/2016 08:17
    8  0000001034MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit    50,000.00  7/20/2016 08:29
    9  0000001037MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit   100,000.00  7/20/2016 08:17
    10 0000001440MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit 1,000,000.00  11/3/2016 14:40
    11 0000001053MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit 1,000,000.00  11/3/2016 14:51
    12 0000001053MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit 5,000,000.00  11/9/2016 15:02
    13 0000001082MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit   500,000.00  11/2/2016 12:47
    14 0000001451MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit 7,000,000.00 11/15/2016 13:12
    15 0000001099MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit 6,404,564.00 11/17/2016 14:23
    16 0000001101MACT800      ADMIN Cash-Deposit    50,000.00  11/2/2016 12:50

function(input, output, session) {    
             dhh  <- reactive({
                inFile <- input$file
                if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
                datatables <- read.csv(input$file[[1, 'datapath']], check.names=FALSE)
                return(datatables)
              })

      output$terry <- renderDataTable({
        if (is.null(dhh)) return(NULL)
        datatables <- data.frame(dhh())
        datatables
      })

              mk <- reactive({
                if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
                inFile <- input$file
                datatable <- read.csv(input$file[[2, 'datapath']], check.names=FALSE)
                return(datatable) 
              })

      output$contents <- renderDataTable({
        if (is.null(mk)) return(NULL)
        datatable <- data.frame(mk())
        datatable
      })

            gloria <- reactive({
                alice <- dhh()
                calvin <- mk()
                x1=calvin[order(nrow(calvin):1),] #invert row order
                ppp <- as.character(alice$Client )
                non <- data.frame(calvin$CLIENTID)
                vcv <- c(ppp)  
                tttt <- as.vector(non)

                r <- calvin[non %in% vcv, ] 

                pipo <- r %>% 
                  mutate(UPDATED.ON=as.Date(factor(r$UPDATED.ON), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))%>% 
                  group_by(r$CLIENTID) %>%  
                  arrange(desc(UPDATED.ON)) %>%
                  slice(1)

         #calculate difference in days
            y <- pipo$UPDATED.ON
            tr <- as.Date(factor(y), format = "%Y/%m/%d")
            jp <- Sys.Date()
            ty <- as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), tr), units="days")
            ty
            ty <- data.frame(ty)
            ty
            #calculate account maintenance fees
            acc <- 60.0885 * ty
            acc

            #calculate amount of money to be deposited to utrade
            jjj <- mk$Amount
            jjj
            tmt <- jjj - acc
            tmt
            class(tmt)

            #converting numeric to string
            tb <- sprintf("%.0f", (tmt))
            tb

            Client <- x1$Client

            btk <- data.frame( Client, "Acc Fees" = acc)
            btk

            uhy <- data.frame(Client, "Amount" = tb, "Reason" = x1$Reason)
            uhy

            names(btk) <- gsub(x = names(btk),
                               pattern = "\\.",
                               replacement = " ")
            btk


            })

          output$marvin <- renderDataTable({
            gloria()

          })}
```

This is much of the code from the server side. I don`t think the ui side will be of any help.

Comment: Kinda hard to tell without a sample of your data. Can you share some of it using dput? Also, dhh and mk - what packages are they from?

Comment: We will need to see the rest of your shiny server function to help. Based on the error it looks like an issue with the `dhh()` and/or `mk()` reactive values.

Comment: @iod , i have added the datasets and other code to do with dhh() and mk(), hopefully this will help out

Comment: @Wil i have added the dhh() and mk()

Comment: I honestly don't see anything in the code you have posted so far that should be causing that error. Are you able to share any more of the shiny app? It would be good to see everything inside `server <- function(input,output){...}` if you can share that.

Comment: @Wil let me do so

Comment: @Wii i have now shared much of it

Comment: I believe the issue is with `jjj <- mk$Amount`. This should be `jjj <- mk()$Amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference the `mk` reactive value without parentheses, which are required because technically the object is a reactive *function*. This should  solve your issue:

```r
jjj <- mk()$Amount
```

Comment: Thanks @Wil , i had not noticed that. It managed to clear away the other error but am now getting a new error  "Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1"

Comment: I am glad you were able to get that cleared up. If my answer helped please accept it so that others can also find it. As far as your new error, that is a separate problem so you will need to post a new question.